# how to change database id in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

how to change database id in sql server?

Comment: i am trying to attach database files , but the server is assigning default ID to database. Can i change ID to custom id no ?

Comment: Are you referring to the ID of rows within a table?  Or something else?

Comment: Are you asking about an autonumber identity field, or the DB_ID?

Comment: sounds like you're talking about the DB_ID, they get assigned automatically when the databases are brought online. Why do you need to change this?

Comment: yes it is DB_ID, is there any way to alter the DB_ID ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite an old question, but just incase anyone else is looking for this it is possible to force a database to have a specific database_id.

The details are here:
[How To Force A Database To Have A Specific ID](http://gumption.co.nz/2016/12/how-to-force-a-database-to-a-specific-database_id/)

But basically the database ID's are created sequentially, so all you need to do is create databases until you get to the number you want.  If the database id is taken you need to detach the database that already has it.  Create the database you want to have it and then re-attach the database which originally had it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
set identity_insert YourTable ON
```

Then delete your row and reinsert it with different identity.

Once you have done the insert don't forget to turn identity_insert off

```
set identity_insert YourTable OFF
```